# How to interpolate GPS data correctly?

Tags: python, gps, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I'm working on a project that involves using linear interpolation to fit lines to 
lat/lng points. I'm pretty new at scientific programming related stuff, and I was wondering if people could steer me in the right direction.What is a good tutorial for linear interpolation in Python, preferably using GIS data?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by fitting lines to lat/long points?  What values are you trying to predict, and are you trying to estimate values between measured locations, or just account for the geographic locations?

Comment: A decent library can interpolate and extrapolate with the same API.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't mention GIS data specifically, you might try reading ["Python for Data Analysis"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) by Wes McKinney. This is a good introduction to the premiere tools for (generic) data analysis in Python: NumPy and Pandas.